# Visual Basic add to timestamp date

Tags: vb.net, timestamp, days

I am adjusting an existing file transfer windows service that renames the file being sent as a timestamp. For testing purposes, I need to make the files sent show up in the destination directory as being ten days ahead of when they were actually sent. Ex: if it's sent on 11/23/2015, it needs to look like it arrived 12/03/2015.

The line of code that generates the file name looks like this:

```
    Dim strFileNameToTransfer As String = My.Settings.FileDirectory.ToString() & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & Format(Now(), "MM") & Format(Now(), "dd")
```

File name shows up in directory like this, if sent on 11/23/2015: 
"20151123.xml"
But I would need it to show up like this:
"20151203.xml"

It would need to adjust the month as well, since the test will cross over into December and it is now November.

Like I said, this is for testing purposes, so it needs to go back to the way it was when testing is over. I really just need a quick fix here, but I know zero about Visual Basic, and I'm still new to programming in general as well. Help!

Comment: things get easier if you forego those old VB functions: `Dim filname As String = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).ToString("yyyyMMdd.x\ml")`  the backslash is not a typo it is to escape the "m"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is add 10 days to the existing date and use that date for your file name. You can also don't need to split the formatting into three different strings.

```
    Dim fileDate = Now().AddDays(10)
    Dim strFileNameToTransfer As String = My.Settings.FileDirectory.ToString() & Format(fileDate, "yyyyMMdd")
```

**EDIT:**

gmiley is right, it is better to use Path.Combine instead of string concatenation

```
Dim NameToTransfer As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Settings.FileDirectory.ToString(), String.Format("{0}.{1}", fileDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), "xml"))
```

Comment: Why not just do: `Dim NameToTransfer As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Setting.FileDirectory.ToString(), String.Format("{0}.{1}", fileDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), "xml")`?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, everyone!